# Laravel update not returning data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My Laravel update operation returns `true` for `dd($data)`. But I want it to return the updated data. How can I change this to get that output? There is one condition I have that the update should be called directly on the model. Any suggestions?

```
$data = FileLogs::find($id)->update([
            'orderId' => $request->orderId, 
            'fileId' => $request->fileId, 
            'status' => $request->status
]);
```

Comment: `update()` will return `boolean`, so you can't use it here. you can make another query after updated the data `$data=FileLogs::find($id)`

Comment: try updateOrCreate instead of update `$data=FileLogs::find($id)->updateOrCreate (['orderId'=>$request->orderId,'fileId'=>$request->fileId,'status'=>$request->status]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $data = tap(FileLogs::find($id))
    ->update(['orderId' => $request->orderId, 'fileId' => $request->fileId, 'status' => $request->status])
    ->first();
 dd($data);
```

Comment: using this without `->first()` at the end returns the updated data.

Comment: @MG you may accept the answer if it solves your problem so that other users could refer this answer for help.

Answer (score 0):

First, update the data then fetch it again

```
$data=FileLogs::find($id)->update(['orderId'=>$request->orderId,'fileId'=>$request->fileId,'status'=>$request->status]);

$updated_data=FileLogs::find($id);

dd($updated_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the data and then you can update it and get it like this

```
$data = FileLogs::find($id);
```

Now update like this

```
$data->update(['orderId'=>$request->orderId,'fileId'=>$request->fileId,'status'=>$request->status]);
```

Now you can do whatever with the data

```
dd($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You can't expect this query will return you an object:

```
$data = FileLogs::find($id)->update([
        'orderId' => $request->orderId, 
        'fileId' => $request->fileId, 
        'status' => $request->status
]);
```

If you want to use Query Builder only as you mentioned in your question, you'll need to get an object manually:

```
$data = FileLogs::where('id', $id)->first();
```

With Eloquent you can use the `updateOrCreate()`:

```
$data = FileLogs::where('id', $id)->updateOrCreate([
        'orderId' => $request->orderId, 
        'fileId' => $request->fileId, 
        'status' => $request->status
]);
```

This will return an object. `update()` will return boolean, so you can't use it here.

Comment: i can't use this method even though it returns data as this would not invoke the `updated` event i have

Comment: You can use `tap` as per @dhairya-lakhera answer.